# Why eloquent property does not exist on this collection instance?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table with column ID, and three text field and the model name is Post

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 256);
        $table->string('slug', 256);
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

While getting data from this table and return the eloquent object from controller and view as `<p>{{$post}}</p>`, it's fine but while accessing the property title as `<p>{{$post->title}}</p>` it's puts an **error**.

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function single($slug){
        $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();
        //return $post;
        return view('posts.single')->withPost($post);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance
```

Comment: `$post` is a collection, not a single `Post`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the first element not the collection :

```
public function single($slug){
    $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
    //return $post;
    return view('posts.single')->withPost($post);
}
```

> Because `get` will always return a collection even if your query could
>   only ever return a single row and `first` returns a single model instance

Comment: @Jobayer Ithink in your migration you mean `$table->string('slug', 256);` not `title` in the second line !!

Comment: Believe me I will give you a thumbs up if you just explain, why previous one is not work but`->first();` is working :)

Comment: Because `get` will always return a collection even if your query could only ever return a single row and `first` returns a single model instance ;)